# Calculating a percentage with SQL based on count of boolean fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table similar to the following table that has feedback information for articles on a website. I want to be able to execute a query to get the total number of responses and the percentage where was_useful is true.

I've tried to run the following based on what I could find online, but it simply says 100% of the results were useful.

```
SELECT p.foreign_key_id,
       count(p.foreign_key_id) AS total_responses,
       count(CASE WHEN p.was_useful=true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / count(p.foreign_key_id) AS percentage_useful
FROM
  table_name p
GROUP BY 
  p.foreign_key_id;
```

Example Table:

```
| id | foreign_key_id | was_useful |  
|----|----------------|------------|  
| 1  | 1              | true       |  
| 2  | 1              | false      |  
| 3  | 1              | true       |  
| 4  | 1              | false      |  
| 5  | 2              | false      |  
| 6  | 2              | false      |  
| 7  | 2              | false      |  
| 8  | 2              | true       |  
| 9  | 3              | false      |  
| 10 | 3              | false      |
```

Current Output:

```
| foreign_key_id | total_responses | percentage_useful |
|----------------|-----------------|-------------------|
| 1              | 4               | 1                 |
| 2              | 4               | 1                 |
| 3              | 2               | 1                 |
```

Desired Output:

```
| foreign_key_id | total_responses | percentage_useful |
|----------------|-----------------|-------------------|
| 1              | 4               | .5                |
| 2              | 4               | .25               |
| 3              | 2               | 0                 |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `AVG()` to calculate the ratio:

```
SELECT p.foreign_key_id, count(*) as total_responses,
       avg( (p.was_useful)::int ) as useful_ratio
FROM table_name p
GROUP BY p.foreign_key_id;
```

I should note that your method -- although much more verbose -- should work.  The problem is that Postgres does integer division.  So, if you change the `then 1` to `then 1.0` it will produce a non-integer value.

Comment: I tried changing the 1 to a 1.0 and that didn't work, but your solution did! Thanks!